# Why is my kitchen ceiling light not turning on with the light switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

My kitchen light is not turning on with light switch, I checked it with a two wire light gadget and when I stick them in a electrical plug socket I get a bright light on the gadget, when I touch the kitchen light switch, the two screws on the right hand side, when light switch is turned on I get a very dim light on that checker, with the light switch off, I get no light at all on the gadget.

Could this mean I need a new light switch?

Comment: Is the bulb good? Did this just happen, or did something change that could have caused it (new fixture installed, new switch installed, etc.).

Answer (score -2):

Agreed that you need to verify the light is not working first by switching the light bulb with a known working light bulb. If that doesn't work is there another 3 way switch that is off now that you didn't know you had?
That was switched off by somebody else since you didn't know it existed.

Can this light only be turned on and off from the one location (i am trying to figure out if this is a single pole or 3 way light switch your testing.)

If its a single pole switch (only two screws with wires under them) than when you put your light up probe on the contacts on the switch it should light either full on or full off. (depending what position you have the switch in , up or down) So if its half on than something is going on.

If its a 3 way switch than maybe your putting the probe on the wrong contacts to get a full light. A three way switch has 3 wires under three different screws.

I am just trying to think out loud because I don't know what to think.

Maybe its a bad ballast (in a fluorescent light fixture) giving off funny voltages which I am not even sure makes sense. What kind of a light is it?

Maybe the neutral in the panel is loose (i know I have had half voltages on plugs when the neutral was loose in the panel even though I wasn't in the panel recently).

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: -1 This answer contains a lot of conjecture. A better format for this style answer is the list the possible causes, methods to test if that is the cause, and the steps needed to correct. Or if you need more input from the OP, add comments requesting clarification to determine which answer to provide.